# Wallet with Tether and ERC20 networks

Tags: erc-20, usdt, usdc, tether

I am just starting my research in blockchain development, and after some time surfing in this website, I realized that it would be better if I ask my specific question by myself.

I am trying to find the most efficient solution to my mobile app wallet idea, which basically allows users to sign up/sign in, and store USDT in Tether and/or ERC20 networks, by depositing them to the user's wallet address. Also, i want to allow users depositing USDC in ERC20 network, as it is stable coin as well.

So far, I was researching about system design of my idea, and already played around with js and solidity code to create ERC20 wallet with depositing and withdrawing some ETH on test nets. I found some questions in here about if I need to create separate ERC20 wallet addresses for different ERC20 tokens(like in my case it is USDT and USDC). On the other hand, I wanted to ask how to make the flow of back end as cheap as possible, as in case if user creates the account, but never actually uses the wallet addresses. Do I have to create ERC20 and Tether wallet address for the user in actual blockchain? Or should I at first create it as local database, and if user decides to deposit tokens, I deposit to my company's wallet address, and then add balance to user's database account, which will act similar to 3rd party and let me control the funds of all users.

I am open to any resources where I can read about my issue, as I know that it might be not enough to get about my question from what I wrote.

Comment: what do you mean by "ERC20 network" , i have never heard about those

Comment: and why the users have to create wallets to use your App, can't they just use their own already existing accounts?

Comment: I meant USDT on Etherium network. My bad. Importing already existing wallet is also an option. What would be the difference between creating wallet and only allowing to import the wallet besides the development difficulty?

Comment: by importing, do you mean handling the private key of the User ??? you need to gain trust for that first! Also you need a good feature list. I don't think you want to compete with Wallet software

Comment: your app should only be needing the signature of the User, no more than that

Comment: The thing is, my point is to create a wallet for payments. User will have ability to deposit stable tokens as USDT and USDC on Tron and Eth networks, and convert from one network to another if needed. The other features will be deposit and withdraw along with staking options. So I was doing research how to design all of these, and was curious about financial side. Like how profitable it will be if I will generate wallet for each new user.

Comment: I am totally new in blockchain, so far I end up palying around with web3py on python by generating wallets on testnets, and fetching the transaction histories from already generated public addresses.